# How to make signal_add fire on Gtk::Layout::put?

Tags: c++, gtkmm

In the following code:

```
Gtk::Layout l;
l.signal_add().connect([](Gtk::Widget* w) -> void {
  std::cout << "Added " << w->get_name() << std::endl;
});
Gtk::Widget* w = // any widget
l.put(*w, 10, 10);
```

nothing gets displayed. For some reason adding via Layout goes around that signal all together. Is there a different signal that can be connected to or to ensure that signal add does get fired?

Answer (score 1):

signal_add gets fired only when you call Gtk::Layout::add (internally - gtk_container_add). I've just checked in the sources, and it seems that gtk_layout_put doesn't emit any signal.
However, you could create your own class, which inherits from the Gtk::Layout class, and override put() method, so it'll emit a signal.